# Need help writing data to a txt file and getting it to save to this file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So I have a project where I am tasked with creating an Application that uses a structure to store the following data about a customers account: last name, first name, customer number, address, city, state, ZIP code, telephone Number, Account Balance, and Date of last payment. 
The application should allow the user to save customer accounts records to the file, search the file for a customer by last name or customer number, and print a report listing all the customer records in the file.

Input validation: When entering a new record, make sure the user enters data for all fields. Do not accept negative numbers for the account balance.

Here is the code I have so far but I am having some issues: 
When I enter the data a file is created but it is 'blank' and I cannot figure out why the informaiton it not saving to the file.

```
Imports System.IO

Imports System.IO.FileStream

Public Class frmCustAcct

    Dim searchFile As StreamReader

    'Declare Structure
    Structure CustomerAccounts
        Dim LastName As String           ' Last name of customer
        Dim FirstName As String         ' First name of customer
        Dim CustomerNumber As String    ' Customer number
        Dim Address As String           ' Address of customer
        Dim City As String              ' City of customer
        Dim State As String             ' State of customer
        Dim ZipCode As Integer          ' Zip code of customer
        Dim TelephoneNumber As Int64    ' Phone number of customer
        Dim AccountBalance As Double    ' Customer account balance
        Dim DateofLastPayment As String ' Date of customer's last payment
    End Structure

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click

        ' Assign Structure Variables
        Dim inputFile As StreamWriter  ' Object variable
        Dim CustomerRecord As CustomerAccounts ' Structure variable

        'Opening Files
        inputFile = File.CreateText("E:\Rio Salado\2014\CIS159 - 11480\HOMEWORK\Chapter 12\Records.txt")

        ' Assign Structure Variables
        CustomerRecord.LastName = txtLast.Text
        CustomerRecord.FirstName = txtFirst.Text
        CustomerRecord.CustomerNumber = txtCustNum.Text()
        CustomerRecord.Address = txtAdd.Text
        CustomerRecord.City = txtCity.Text
        CustomerRecord.State = txtState.Text
        CustomerRecord.ZipCode = CInt(txtZip.Text)
        CustomerRecord.TelephoneNumber = CInt(txtTeleNum.Text)
        CustomerRecord.AccountBalance = CDbl(txtAcctBal.Text)
        While CustomerRecord.AccountBalance < 0
            CustomerRecord.AccountBalance = CDbl(InputBox("Enter non-Negative Balance"))
        End While
        CustomerRecord.DateofLastPayment = CStr(CDate(txtLastPay.Text))

        'Write the data to the file. 
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.LastName)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.FirstName)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.CustomerNumber)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.Address)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.City)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.State)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.ZipCode)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.TelephoneNumber)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.AccountBalance)
        inputFile.WriteLine(CustomerRecord.DateofLastPayment)
        ClearFields()

    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SearchToolStripMenuItem.Click

        'Open File to Search Existing
        searchFile = File.OpenText("E:\Rio Salado\2014\CIS159 - 11480\HOMEWORK\Chapter 12\Records.txt")
        Dim LastName As String
        Dim Flag As Integer
        Flag = 0
        'Retrieve the Record Name
        LastName = InputBox("Enter Last Name to Search")
        Dim CSearchRecord As CustomerAccounts
        Try
            While Not searchFile.EndOfStream
                CSearchRecord.LastName = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.FirstName = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.CustomerNumber = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.Address = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.City = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.State = searchFile.ReadLine()
                CSearchRecord.ZipCode = CInt(searchFile.ReadLine())
                CSearchRecord.TelephoneNumber = CLng(searchFile.ReadLine())
                CSearchRecord.AccountBalance = CDbl(searchFile.ReadLine())
                CSearchRecord.DateofLastPayment = searchFile.ReadLine()
                'Compare Current Record With Searched
                If CSearchRecord.LastName.Equals(LastName) Then
                    Flag = 1
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
            'If Record Found Display Appropriate Fields
            If Flag.Equals(1) Then
                txtLast.Text = CSearchRecord.LastName.ToString()
                txtFirst.Text = CSearchRecord.FirstName.ToString()
                txtCustNum.Text = CSearchRecord.CustomerNumber.ToString()
                txtAdd.Text = CSearchRecord.Address.ToString()
                txtCity.Text = CSearchRecord.City.ToString()
                txtState.Text = CSearchRecord.State.ToString()
                txtZip.Text = CSearchRecord.ZipCode.ToString()
                txtTeleNum.Text = CSearchRecord.TelephoneNumber.ToString()
                txtAcctBal.Text = CSearchRecord.AccountBalance.ToString()
                txtLastPay.Text = CSearchRecord.DateofLastPayment.ToString()
            Else
                'if not tell user no record Exists
                MessageBox.Show("No Record Found")
                ClearFields()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReportToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ReportToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Dim report As String
        report = "Report of Customer Accounts" + vbNewLine
        ' Open a File in Read Mode
        searchFile = File.OpenText("E:\Rio Salado\2014\CIS159 - 11480\HOMEWORK\Chapter 12\Records.txt")
        Try
            'Reading the file until complete
            While Not searchFile.EndOfStream
                report += searchFile.ReadLine() + ""
                report += searchFile.ReadLine() + ""
                report += searchFile.ReadLine() + ""
                report += searchFile.ReadLine() + ""
                report += vbNewLine
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        'Display Report
        MessageBox.Show(report)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ClearFields()
        txtAcctBal.clear()
        txtadd.clear()
        txtCity.Clear()
        txtFirst.Clear()
        txtLast.Clear()
        txtCustNum.clear()
        txtLastPay.Clear()
        txtState.Clear()
        txtTeleNum.clear()
        txtZip.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click

        'Close the Form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am new to Visual basic and would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you do not close your file or flush the buffer. You'll at least need to do fileYouCreated.close() when you're done writing to it. Check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_file_handling.htm and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304427 for additional info on reading/writing to files.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the data to save to the file